# tree where elements can be moved around

Tags: python, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure that allows moving of sub-trees.

I have a list of elements, e.g. `[('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('B', 'C')]`.

When I use a normal tree I only get:

```
A--B
C--D
B--C
```

But I would like to have:

```
+--B
|
A
|
+--C---D
```

Is there a known data structure to do this?

Comment: A dict of dicts

Comment: can you give an example I do not understand how a dictionary of dictionaries would link the two parts together